# Decoding URLEncoded non standard characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, urlencode

I am trying to decode some text sent from a server that is URLEncoded, and this is the best method I managed to find.

I use these standard functions for URLEncododing:

```
NSString* encodeToPercentEscapeString(NSString *string) {
    return (__bridge NSString *)
    CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef) string,
                                        NULL,
                                        (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}

NSString* decodeFromPercentEscapeString(NSString *string) {
    return (__bridge NSString *)
    CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL,
                                                        (__bridge CFStringRef) string,
                                                        CFSTR(""),
                                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}
```

If I encode special characters:

```
NSString* encoded = encodeToPercentEscapeString(@"ąśżźćęółń");
```

I get @"%C4%85%C5%9B%C5%BC%C5%BA%C4%87%C4%99%C3%B3%C5%82%C5%84"

which is ok.

But if I try to decode it:

```
NSString* original = decodeFromPercentEscapeString(encoded);
```

I get :@"ńÖŇõŇľŇļńáńô√≥ŇāŇĄ".

Why?

Is there a better method to decode URLEncoded text?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `-[NSString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]`?

Also, you are using the bridging casts incorrectly.  The created strings will leak, because ARC doesn't know it owns them.  Use CFBridgingRelease().  It's nice because it is a variant of CFRelease() which is normally necessary to balance a Core Foundation "Create" function, but it cooperates with ARC.

Comment: Yes, i have. The same thing happens. Thanks for the tip on the bridge casts though.

Comment: I think there must be some other problem.  A quick test in Python, just using your encoded string, shows the correct output:
    $ python
    >>> from CoreFoundation import *
    >>> CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(None, u"%C4%85%C5%9B%C5%BC%C5%BA%C4%87%C4%99%C3%B3%C5%82%C5%84", u"", kCFStringEncodingUTF8).encode('utf8')
    '\xc4\x85\xc5\x9b\xc5\xbc\xc5\xba\xc4\x87\xc4\x99\xc3\xb3\xc5\x82\xc5\x84'

Comment: Yes, but it looks as if for some reason pairs of bytes which should be treated as one character are treated as two. Meaning that \xc4\x85 translate to ńÖ instead of ą

Comment: In your question, you state "I get" to describe the results. How are you getting that? I just took your code and tested and everything works fine for me. I used `NSLog()` to check the results. I removed the ARC-isms because I'm using Xcode 3.2.6 on Snow Leopard, but that's it.

Comment: I use NSLog too, but on Xcode 4.3.2, and Lion compiling for 5.1. I am starting to think that this might be a bug in my version of ios/devtools.